# How to handle application errors for json api calls using CakePHP?

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.4.

I want my frontend make api calls to my CakePHP backend using ajax.

Suppose this is to change passwords.

Change password action can throw the following application errors:

1. old password wrong
2. new password and confirm new passwords do not match

In my frontend, I have a success callback handler and a error callback handler.

The error callback handler handles all the non 200 request calls such as when I throw NotFoundException or UnAuthorizedAccessException in my action.

The success callback handler handles all the 200 request calls including of course, the above 2 scenarios.

My questions are:

1. Should I continue to do it this way? Meaning to say, inside all success callback handler, I need to watch out for application success and application error scenarios.
2. Should I send application errors back with actual HTTP error codes?

if I should do 2, how do I implement this in CakePHP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use http error codes for system errors like:

1. old password wrong
2. new password and confirm new passwords do not match
3. etc etc...

Now using success handler you can show messages and code flow as:

Create Ajax post or get to submit the form, I am showing you post example

```
var passwordValue = $('#password').val();
$.post( "/updatePassword", { passwordText: passwordValue })
                .done(function(response) {
                 if(response.status === 'Success'){
                    // Success msg
                    // whatever                   
                 }else{
                    // Error msg
                    // whatever     
                 }

                });
```

json response would like:

```
 {
"status": "Failed/Success",
"message": "old password wrong."
 }
```

Create one function in controller

```
public function updatePassword() {

$myModel = $this->MyModel->find('first' // YOUR CODE LOGIC);

if($this->request->is('ajax') {
    $this->layout=null;
    // What else?
    echo json_encode($myModel);
    exit;
    // What else?

  }
}
```

Do something like this, hope it will solve your query!